# How to set beep sound (warning) in real-time with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mongodb

I don't know how to put in function 'beep' if value of `(this['informasibencana']) > 1` and sound has activated. I would to try like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  done();
});

function done() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    updates();
    done();
  }, 200);
}

function updates() {
  $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
    $("#count").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function() {
      $("#count").append("Total: " + this['informasibencana'] + "");
      if (this['informasibencana'] > 0) {
        beep();
      } else { }
    });
  });
}

function beep() {
  var snd = new Audio(src="warning.wav");  
  snd.play();
}
```

But there was repeating sound.

And here is fetch.php

```
include_once('db.php');
        $query = $db->informasibencana;
        $nosql = array("status"=>"pending");
        $result = $query->find($nosql);
        $informasibencana = $result->count();
        $result = array();
        array_push($result, array('informasibencana'=>$informasibencana));  
        echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

Comment: The sound repeats because you call `beep()` once for every item in the `data.result` array. The `audio` element will not loop by default.

Comment: What JSON is returned from the `fetch.php` page?

Comment: Sorry, i'm beginner in jQuery. I just want to get value from count. Can you look at my edited post again ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the beep function to pause the audio after 2seconds (or as per your need):

```
function beep() {
  var snd = new Audio(src="warning.wav");  
  snd.play();
  setTimeout(snd.remove(), 2000);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It works to controlling duration of sound. But, I want to call function of beep sound while this['informasibencana'] > 1 then the sound has activated.